# create an array and a function allowing deletion zeros rom the array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, compression

i have a code that create an array of 7 integers than the system have a function that check where array[i] == 0  will place zeros at the most right of the array and at the end the system display the original array and the compressed array like this

original array:

0 5 0 12 0 0 4

compressed array :

5 12 4 0 0 0 0

can anyone help me ??

this is the code

```
package question3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayWithCompression {

    static int[] array = new int[7];

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("enter numbers");
        for(int i = 0 ; i< array.length; i++){

            array[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(compression(array));
    }

    public static int[] compression(int[] newarray){

        for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++ ){

            if(array[i] == 0){
                    array[i] = i++;
            }
            array[i] = newarray[i];
        }
        return newarray;
    }
}
```

Comment: array[i] = i++;  why this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to the right answer. I suggest you step through your code in your debugger to see what you are doing.

Since it is hard to give you a hint without giving you the answer...

```
 public static int[] compression(int[] array){
      int j = 0;
      // iterate over all the numbers in the array.
      for (int i : array)
          // if the number is not 0 add it back into the array
          if (i != 0)
              // add it back only counting non-0 for the index
             array[j++] = i;
      // fill the rest of the array with zero.
      Arrays.fill(array, j, array.length, 0);
 }
```

Comment: @gebratag I have added comments now, is there anything specific you would like to know more about?

Comment: @gebratag note this is O(N) time instead of O(N^2) time (and O(1) for space)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code in your compression method:

```
  public static int[] compression(int[] newarray){
    int []arr= new int[newarray.length];
    int j=0;
    for(int i = 0; i< newarray.length; i++ ){

        if(newarray[i] != 0){
            arr[j++] = newarray[i];
        }
    }
    return arr;
  }
```

without using other array :

```
   public static int[] compression(int[] newarray){

    for(int i = 0; i< newarray.length; i++ ){

        if(newarray[i] != 0){
            continue;
        }else
        {
            for(int j = i; j< newarray.length; j++)
            {
                if(newarray[j] != 0)
                {
                    newarray[i]=newarray[j];
                    newarray[j]= 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newarray;
   }
```

and you can change your main method (printing array ) :

```
    array= compression(array);
    for(int i = 0 ; i< array.length; i++){

        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

Comment: i tried your solution and this is the output a get   ......... enter numbers
0
5
0
12
0
0
4
[I@6f580c3a

Comment: it printed object value. get the object in another array and loop it to print all values.

Comment: i am not allow to use another array it cann't be done in one array ?

Comment: @gebratag you have to print using loop or you can write toString() method if you don't want to write every time loop

Comment: @gebratag : you can do that also

Comment: yes i used and still display this output ///////here the change that i made **System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));**......enter numbers
0
5
12
0
0
4
2
[5, 12, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[I@7d8aecf1

Comment: i have added code @gebratag that is not using any other array and you can change your main method also as above.

Comment: @Prashant Note: you can solve this in O(N) time and O(1) space.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it out like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - i; i++) {// loop decreases as after each loop a zero if found is put at last
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) { // this loop puts first 0 in last by swapping each nos.
        if (arr[j] == 0) {
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            arr[j + 1] = 0;
        }
    }
}
return arr;
```

and in main function:

```
array = compression(array);
for (int i : array) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```